# Android Studio build/apk not visible

Tags: android-studio, directory, apk

I'm using the Crashlytics plugin for beta testing, but the only way to upload an apk is to drag it from within Android Studio. In the terminal, I can access `<app>/build/apk/`, but in Android Studio, that folder is not showing up (I can see `dex`, `lint` etc). Any idea how to display it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Studio automatically hides certain directories to reduce the load of indexing all those files. If you look in your module's iml file (e.g. root/main_module/main_module.iml), you'll see this line:

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk" />
```

If you remove that line, it will start showing root/main_module/build/apk/ in the file tree.

Unfortunately, Android Studio is smart enough to notice that it's missing and will add it again when it builds, so it's not really worth doing.

You can see a little more of the conversation I've had with one of the Googler's on the Android Studio project here: https://plus.google.com/104239612059033457922/posts/RVq9e9Viux5

Comment: I don't even have //$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk in my .iml file!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I wrote this some time ago (long before Android Studio 1.0) so it may no longer be up-to-date. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: You can copy the apk somewhere (~/Desktop) and drag it into the Crashlytics (Fabric)'s plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As for Android Studio 4.1.3 in year 2021, my best response is: Go into the project view of your project, click 'app' in the top bar of the project view for the file path of "yourProject/app", the 'build' directory will show up in a list along with 'src' automatically. Select the 'build' directory with your mouse and then you can get into all the sub-directories of the 'build', including 'outputs' for apk generated.