# where is generated .apk file in android studio 1.0 RC1

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am new to android studio, I had tried to find .apk file  but in this version (1.0 RC1)there is no build/optputs folder in project folder. I run the program on simulator it runs well but I did not got the apk file. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same place `app\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: @PedroOliveira  yes after click on show in explorer I got it. Thanks

Comment: There are 2 apk files. 1.app-beta-debug.apk 2. app-beta-debug-unaligned.apk which one to use?

Comment: The app-beta-debug.apk. The unaligned apk is an intermediate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170818/android-studio-build-apk-not-visible